# Opencl: creating UserEvent from c style pointer

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm trying to recreate a UserEvent object from a C pointer that is returned from another part of the code:

```
uintptr_t get_event_ptr(); // returns cl_event pointer to user event, comes from pyopencl


uintptr_t evt_ptr = get_event_ptr();
```

Events in C++ have the following constructor:

```
Event (const cl_event &event, bool retainObject=false)
```

But UserEvents have no such constructor. All they have is:

```
UserEvent (const Context &context, cl_int *err=NULL)
UserEvent ()
```

I've tried doing a static cast, a reinterpret cast and a dynamic cast, to no avail:

`dynamic_cast`

```
cl::UserEvent* ue = dynamic_cast<cl::UserEvent*> (new cl::Event(*((const cl_event*) evt_ptr)));

error: 'cl::Event' is not polymorphic
```

`static_cast`

```
cl::UserEvent* ue = static_cast<cl::UserEvent*> (new cl::Event(*((const cl_event*) evt_ptr)));

ue->setStatus(CL_COMPLETE);

Segmentation fault: 11
```

`reinterpret_cast`

```
cl::UserEvent* ue = reinterpret_cast<cl::UserEvent*> (new cl::Event(*((const cl_event*) evt_ptr)));

ue->setStatus(CL_COMPLETE);

Segmentation fault: 11
```

`using parent constructor`

```
cl::UserEvent* ue = new cl::UserEvent((const cl_event&)(*((const cl_event*) evt_ptr)));

error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'cl::UserEvent'
```

How can I recreate the UserEvent from a C pointer?

Answer (score 0):

cl_event is typedef'd as a pointer, not an opencl abstract type. Therefore, it should be set AS evt_ptr, and not as *evt_ptr.

```
cl::UserEvent* ue = static_cast<cl::UserEvent*> (new cl::Event((cl_event) evt_ptr));

ue->setStatus(CL_COMPLETE);
```

works just fine